# How to automatically make all youtube links on a site open in fancybox 3 lightbox

Tags: javascript, youtube, lightbox, fancybox-3

I'm wondering if/how it's possible to make all youtube links open in Fancybox 3.

Scenario: A website has a bunch of links to youtube. Looking for a way to automatically pop up those video clicks into a lightbox without adding "data-fancybox" to every single link.

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxx"> </a>
```

I have not been able to find any examples of getting fancybox-3 to automatically capture links from a certain URL...

UPDATE:

Much appreciate demon's answer but I'm looking for a way to do it with no markup changes to the actual youtube links.

I could not find any example but started looking for automatic capture of image links.

This is close and I feel that something LIKE this would work, but seems to capture every single link, not just the ones with "youtube" in it.

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).has('youtube')) {
        $(this).fancybox();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: updated with my code that doesn't work... but hopefully the idea of it is better communicated

Comment: Not clear why you're being downvoted so harshly. You're on a good track. You should do some digging on finding elements by their HREF value. I don't think `.has()` is what you're looking for, but you're getting close.

Comment: E.g., for each 'a' element, you may want to look at the `href` property of the element, and see if it contains something like `youtube.com/`. If yes, then you could apply fancybox, or apply a new class (programmatically) to that element, as in Demon's answer.

Comment: Why do you not want to just add `data-fancybox` to the links instead of writing some jquery code to identify youtube links? Fancybox 3 recognizes a youtube or Vimeo link easily and opens it in the lightbox by just adding the data attribute.  Your making it more complex than it really needs to be. You should use the plugin as it is designed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just add data-fancybox to the links but this should work if you just can't force yourself to do that ;-) .

```
 $('a[href*="https://www.youtube.com/watch?"]').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-fancybox','');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

So I would simple jQuery to get all the links in the youtube links
You would probably want to do something like add a class to the anchor `<a class=" fancy-box video-link">LINK</a>`

```
var $links = $('.video-link');

$links.on('click', function() {

    $.fancybox.open( $links, {
        // Custom options
       //add props to <a> where we have video-link set
       $(this).props('data-fancybox');
    }, $links.index( this ) );

    return false;
```

Comment: I never used fancy box but i just looked at their docs and examples.

Comment: This answer is good but could be improved by dropping jQuery, and not requiring markup modification. You could simply check the `href `attribute for `youtube` or something similar instead.

Comment: That could be good idea as well. but the OP may want to use other links may be short links or NOT youtube links

Comment: Ah sorry I had an old revision of the question still loaded that asked for a solution explicitly not changing any markup. As you were!

Comment: hoping to not have to mark up the links. see updated question for a non-working code example

Comment: you want to be careful if you are using the each function. each is a very slow function I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in the future so here is my quick implementation which also works for Vimeo links...

```
( function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Define matching provider url sources
     * @type {Object}
     */
    var mediaPatterns = {
        youtube: [
            'https?:\/\/((m|www)\.)?youtube\.com\/watch.*',
            'https?:\/\/youtu\.be/.*'
        ],
        vimeo: [
            'https?:\/\/(.+\.)?vimeo\.com\/.*'
        ]
    };

    /**
     * Check we have Fancybox available
     */
    if ( $.fancybox ) {

        /**
         * Attach event listener to all link tags
         */
        $( document ).on( 'click', 'a', function() {

            /**
             * Clicked link element
             * @type {Object}
             */
            var $link = $( this );

            /**
             * Clicked link href value
             * @type {String}
             */
            var href = $link.attr( 'href' );

            /**
             * Loop through each defined pattern group
             */
            for ( var provider in mediaPatterns ) {

                /**
                 * Patterns for this provider
                 * @type {Array}
                 */
                var patterns = mediaPatterns[ provider ];

                /**
                 * Loop through each pattern for this provider
                 */
                for ( let i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++ ) {

                    /**
                     * Convert string patter to regular expression
                     * @type {RegExp}
                     */
                    var pattern = new RegExp( patterns[ i ], 'i' );

                    /**
                     * Check if the link href matches our pattern
                     */
                    if ( href.match( pattern ) ) {

                        /**
                         * Boom, open fancybox
                         */
                        $.fancybox.open( $link );

                        /**
                         * Prevent default
                         */
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
    }

} )( jQuery || window.jQuery );
```

This works for dynamically created e.g. elements that have been added to the page after initial load.

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/hu8cjgk3/

Only tested on Fancybox 3.5.7+.